# Mapping csv to java in smooks programatically can't handle empty Double

Tags: java, parsing, csv, smooks

I'm using smooks library to parse csv files fast and easy, mapping them programmatically to POJOs.
But I have troubles handling empty fields on POJO's Double attributes. For example, the java object has:

```
public class MulticashHeader {

        // ...
    private Double c06;
    private static Double c07;
    private Double c08;
    private Double c09;
    private String c10;
    // ...
    public Double getC06_SaldoInicial() {
        return c06_SaldoInicial;
    }
    /**
     * @param c06_SaldoInicial the c06_SaldoInicial to set
     */
    public void setC06_SaldoInicial(Double c06_SaldoInicial) {
        if (c06_SaldoInicial != null)
            this.c06_SaldoInicial = c06_SaldoInicial;
    }
    public void setC06_SaldoInicial(String c06_SaldoInicial) {
        if (c06_SaldoInicial != null && !"".equals(c06_SaldoInicial.trim()) ) {
            this.c06_SaldoInicial = new Double(c06_SaldoInicial.trim());
        } else {
            this.c06_SaldoInicial = Double.valueOf("0");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the c07_TotalDebitos
     */
    public Double getC07_TotalDebitos() {
        return c07_TotalDebitos;
    }
    /**
     * @param c07_TotalDebitos the c07_TotalDebitos to set
     */
    public void setC07_TotalDebitos(Double c07_TotalDebitos) {
        MulticashEncabezado.c07_TotalDebitos = c07_TotalDebitos;
    }
    public void setC07_TotalDebitos(String c07_TotalDebitos) {
        if (c07_TotalDebitos != null && !"".equals(c07_TotalDebitos.trim()) ) {
            MulticashEncabezado.c07_TotalDebitos = new Double(c07_TotalDebitos.trim());
        } else {
            MulticashEncabezado.c07_TotalDebitos = Double.valueOf("0");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the c08_TotalCreditos
     */
    public Double getC08_TotalCreditos() {
        return c08_TotalCreditos;
    }
    /**
     * @param c08_TotalCreditos the c08_TotalCreditos to set
     */
    public void setC08_TotalCreditos(Double c08_TotalCreditos) {
        if (c08_TotalCreditos != null)
            this.c08_TotalCreditos = c08_TotalCreditos;
    }
    public void setC08_TotalCreditos(String c08_TotalCreditos) {
        if (c08_TotalCreditos != null && !"".equals(c08_TotalCreditos.trim()) ) {
            this.c08_TotalCreditos = new Double( c08_TotalCreditos.trim() );
        } else {
            this.c08_TotalCreditos = Double.valueOf("0");
        }
    }
        // ...
}
```

And the smooks mapping goes like this:

```
private static final char CchrSeparator = ';';
// File mapping
private static final String CMulticashHeader = "c01_ClaveBanco,c02_Cuenta,c03_Consecutivo,c04_FechaMovimientos,c05_ClaveMoneda,c06_SaldoInicial,c07_TotalDebitos,"+
        "c08_TotalCreditos,c09_SaldoFinal,c10_TipoCuenta,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18_NumeroMovs";
smooks.setReaderConfig( new CSVReaderConfigurator( CMulticashHeader ).setBinding( new CSVBinding(
                            "balanceList", MulticashHeader.class, CSVBindingType.LIST )).setSeparatorChar(CchrSeparator) );
```

But when processing a file with empty values for c_06, c_07, c_08 and c_09 (not just zeros but empty), which happen to be Double values, even setting function overloading on POJO's attribute setter does not work and throws

```
Unable to filter InputStream for target profile [org.milyn.profile.Profile#default_profile].
org.milyn.SmooksException: Unable to filter InputStream for target profile [org.milyn.profile.Profile#default_profile].
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.filter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:294)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.doFilter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:243)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.doFilter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:216)
        at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:516)
        at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:475)
        at com.example.CSVParserServicio.runSmooksTransform(CSVParserServicio.java:98)
        ...
Caused by: org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode binding value '' for property 'c07_TotalDebitos' on bean '9b06d0eb-9231-
4c49-a612-75ace2b5d44c'.
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeDataString(BeanInstancePopulator.java:581)
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeAndSetPropertyValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:482)
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.bindDomDataValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:384)
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.visitAfter(BeanInstancePopulator.java:319)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter$ElementProcessor.processMapping(SmooksDOMFilter.java:778)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter$ElementProcessor.process(SmooksDOMFilter.java:717)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter$ElementProcessor.access$000(SmooksDOMFilter.java:666)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.filter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:385)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.filter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:317)
        at org.milyn.delivery.dom.SmooksDOMFilter.filter(SmooksDOMFilter.java:292)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode Double value ''.
        at org.milyn.javabean.decoders.DoubleDecoder.decode(DoubleDecoder.java:34)
        at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeDataString(BeanInstancePopulator.java:579)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:992)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
        at org.milyn.javabean.decoders.DoubleDecoder.decode(DoubleDecoder.java:32)
        ... 37 more
```

Does anoyone how to avoid this trap keeping the programmatic approach?

**----------------EDIT----------------:** 
I'm testing this in the smooks example fro csv-to-java, using a config xml as Tom says. I have this and the error replicates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                      xmlns:csv1="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.3.xsd">

    <csv1:reader fields="firstName,lastName,gender,age,country" separator=";">
        <csv1:listBinding beanId="customerList" class="example.Customer"/>
    </csv1:reader>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

The file is

```
charles;moulliard;Male;43;belgium
maxence;dewil;Male;;belgium
eleonor;moulliard;Female;12;belgium
```

(note the empty age). And the java main class is

```
private static String messageIn = readInputMessage();

Smooks smooks = new Smooks("/route/to/smooks-config.xml");

        try {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = smooks.createExecutionContext();
            JavaResult result = new JavaResult();
            smooks.filterSource(executionContext, new StringSource(messageIn), result);
            return (List) result.getBean("customerList");
        } finally {
            smooks.close();
        }
        ...
```

I found out that it's Tom's example (!!!), so I ask: how to map csv fields to POJO attributes using `<jb:bean>`?

**---------------- EDIT2 ----------------:**
I tried something I found in a codehaus' JIRA thread and I got the following config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                      xmlns:csv1="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.3.xsd"
                      xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.1.xsd">

    <csv1:reader fields="firstName,lastName,gender,age,country" separator=";" />

    <jb:bindings beanId="customer" class="example.Customer" createOnElement="csv-record">
        <jb:value property="firstName" data="csv-record/firstName" />
        <jb:value property="lastName" data="csv-record/lastName" />
        <jb:value property="gender" data="csv-record/gender" />
        <jb:value property="age" data="csv-record/age" decoder="Integer" default="0"  />
        <jb:value property="country" data="csv-record/country" />
    </jb:bindings>

    <jb:bindings beanId="customerList" class="java.util.ArrayList" createOnElement="csv-set">
        <jb:wiring beanIdRef="customer" />
    </jb:bindings>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

It works using the CSV with the empty Integer (age) shown before BUT it fails when I update javabean xsd above 1.1. Throws the error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jb:bindings'. One of '{"http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd":abstract-reader, "http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd":abstract-resource-config}' is expected
```

¿Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the CSV shorthand binding mechanism there, which doesn't allow you to specify defaults.  I think your options will be...

1. Modify the CSVBinding code to meet your needs.
2. Use one of the more verbose config mechansism i.e. the xml `<jb:bean>` [configs](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.5%3aSmooks_v1.5_User_Guide#Java_Binding_Configuration_Details) or the [programmatic config](http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.5%3aSmooks_v1.5_User_Guide#Programmatic_Configuration_7).  Either of these will let you specify a default value.

Comment: Sorry if I don't get it straight at once but... does this mean that setting the binding using beanXYZ.bindTo() provides some method to set up a default value? Also, don't see clearly how to use bindTo with a CSV that doesn't have column names like XML nodes.

Comment: Sorry... I thought there was an API mechanism for setting the default, but I checked and there isn't.  That said... you can do it easily enough by overriding a decoder supplied to the bindTo method e.g. bindTo("a/b/c", new DoubleDecoder() { void decode(String data) {....}})

Comment: Please check the edit to the question. I tried your(?) example, trying to replicate scenario and I got to a point I don't know how to map CSV fields to attributes of POJO.

Comment: Added a new edit. Troubled only with xsd version, otherwise it works! Thanks for your guide... it was the light at the end of the tunnel!