# How to handle and display log for DataDecodeException in java class

Tags: java, exception, handler, smooks

I am read the csv file to java so i got DataDecodeException so how can i handlle the exception ,
  upto that i handle smooks exception and print the log like this "org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source." but i need to print log like this org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode binding value 'A' for property 'telcoId' on bean 'customer'. how can i achived this?

Exception:

```
15:24:18,471 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- INFO 2012-11-01 15:24:18,471 [] MigrationCustomerHome - CSV File ..C:\Users\PEDDU\AppData\Local\Temp\-3dd9162f-13abbd6ef67--7f5a5802617468662164441.upload
15:24:18,479 FATAL [application] org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:91)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:324)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:299)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:256)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:469)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.process(RewriteFilter.java:98)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:57)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.milyn.SmooksException: Failed to filter source.
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:86)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:61)
    at org.milyn.Smooks._filter(Smooks.java:516)
    at org.milyn.Smooks.filterSource(Smooks.java:475)
    at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.runSmooksTransform(MigrationCustomerHome.java:271)
    at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome.migrateCustomers(MigrationCustomerHome.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConversationInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:47)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at com.manam.mobee.migrationCustomerManagement.MigrationCustomerHome_$$_javassist_seam_10.migrateCustomers(MigrationCustomerHome_$$_javassist_seam_10.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode binding value 'A' for property 'telcoId' on bean 'customer'.
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeDataString(BeanInstancePopulator.java:581)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeAndSetPropertyValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:482)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.bindSaxDataValue(BeanInstancePopulator.java:418)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.visitAfter(BeanInstancePopulator.java:348)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.visitAfter(SAXHandler.java:389)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.endElement(SAXHandler.java:204)
    at org.milyn.delivery.SmooksContentHandler.endElement(SmooksContentHandler.java:83)
    at org.milyn.csv.CSVReader.parse(CSVReader.java:379)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:70)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:75)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode Long value 'A'.
    at org.milyn.javabean.decoders.LongDecoder.decode(LongDecoder.java:52)
    at org.milyn.javabean.BeanInstancePopulator.decodeDataString(BeanInstancePopulator.java:579)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at org.milyn.javabean.decoders.LongDecoder.decode(LongDecoder.java:50)
    ... 109 more
```

smaplecode :

```
try {
    //smooks Exception
} catch (SmooksException e) {

log.info("Smooks Exception   "+e);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977975/mapping-csv-to-java-in-smooks-programatically-cant-handle-empty-double

Comment: thanx responding ,but i dnt want this i need how to dispaly caused by exception (DataDecodeException ) in java class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your goal is but I am guessing that you want to see a full stack trace in your log instead of just a single line. If this is the case you need to use `log.error("Some message", e)` instead of `log.info("Some message " + e)`.

--- Edit based on OP's comment ---

Here is a sample code that gives you what you want. It traverses the stack trace and digs out the first cause of a certain type. It can be extended to handle cases when the desired type of cause occurs multiple times and you are interested in the 2nd, 3rd, etc. occurence:

```
try {
    throw new Exception(
        new Exception(
            new Exception(
                new RuntimeException("This is the one I am interested in", new RuntimeException()))));

} catch (Exception e) {
    dig(e);
}

private void dig(Throwable e) {
    if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
        log.info("Some message " + e);

    } else if (e != null) {
        dig(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Attila ,No my goal is i want to print single line but it was only  Caused by: org.milyn.javabean.DataDecodeException: Failed to decode binding value 'A' for property 'telcoId' on bean 'customer'.  message

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new custom exception and then trow it.
You can name it the way you want .

Here is an example which describes procedure to create custom exceptions : http://java2novice.com/java_exception_handling_examples/create_custom_exception/

Comment: thax Mangesh but caused by exception is not custome exception its predefind exception,custom exception which we derived the exception is know as custom exception right

Comment: you could catch the exception and then throw your desired exception.In your case handle "SmooksException" in try block and in catch block for "SmooksException" you can throw "DataDecodeException" along with message.